# Iphone X horizontal scroll in chrome

Tags: html, ios

When the initial-scale=0.6,minimum-scale=0.6 and maximum-scale-0.6 the content overflows in iphone X and iphone 11 chrome browsers but works in safari and also works in devices without notch, issue is only in chrome browser with notch iphone devices. Is there a way to fix? as i want the desktop design to fit in landscape mode for this im giving initial-scale=0.6 so that it can accommodate the desktop design.

Comment: yeah... that happens sometimes. I'd encourage you to try asking a question rather than just stating a fact.

Comment: what could be the issue,how will i be able to fix this? @holex